# Sorting a list of objects using Linq based on a property of the object that is an array of strings

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a List(of MatrixComponent) which I am trying to sort.

```
Public Class MatrixComponent
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Matrix As Integer 
    Public Property Output As String
    Public Property Sorts As String()
End Class
```

I need to sort the list:

1. by the Output property (a file path, string)
2. on each array value in the object's Sorts property

The number of elements in the Sorts array can vary from one object to the next, but if the array has 3 elements, it will have 3 string values, any of which could be an empty string.

Example:

Keep in mind, my sample data is using numbers stored as strings, because I find them easier to look at, however, the values in the array are strings and should be sorted as strings. You could essentially have an array containing the following {"10", "abc", "1abc5d"}

```
Dim m As New List(Of MatrixComponent)
m.Add(New MatrixComponent() With {.Id = 1, .Output = "c:\a.pdf", .Sorts = {"10", "30"}})
m.Add(New MatrixComponent() With {.Id = 2, .Output = "c:\a.pdf", .Sorts = {"10"}})
m.Add(New MatrixComponent() With {.Id = 3, .Output = "c:\a.pdf", .Sorts = {"10", "20"}})
m.Add(New MatrixComponent() With {.Id = 4, .Output = "c:\a.pdf", .Sorts = {}})
m.Add(New MatrixComponent() With {.Id = 5, .Output = "c:\a.pdf", .Sorts = {"9", "1"}})
m.Add(New MatrixComponent() With {.Id = 6, .Output = "c:\a.pdf", .Sorts = {"10"}})
```

I am expecting the following order:

```
4, 2, 6, 3, 1, 5

Id             Col1       col2     col3
=======================================
4              NULL       NULL     NULL
2              10         NULL     NULL
6              10         NULL     NULL
3              10         20       NULL
1              10         30       NULL
5              9          1        NULL


id=4, sort=""
id=2, sort="10"
id=6, sort="10"
id=3, sort="10", "20"
id=1, sort="10", "30"
id=5, sort="9", "1"
```

I was able to achieve the correct order with the following Linq query:

```
Dim sorted As IOrderedEnumerable(Of MatrixComponent) =
items.OrderBy(Function(u) u.Output) _
.ThenBy(Function(y) If(y.Sorts Is Nothing, "", y.Sorts(0))) _
.ThenBy(Function(y) If(y.Sorts Is Nothing OrElse y.Sorts.Length <= 1, "", y.Sorts(1))) _
.ThenBy(Function(y) If(y.Sorts Is Nothing OrElse y.Sorts.Length <= 2, "", y.Sorts(2)))
```

Comment: whats that stuff at the bottom?  what does "sorts" look like?

Comment: It will be problematic if some item arrays can be less than 3 elements, null  or contain `String.Empty`

Comment: Are the `Sorts` arrays themselves already sorted?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry to get out the door yesterday. I have updated the post with a clearer picture of what I'm trying to accomplish, the issue, and what I have tried already.

Comment: ThenBy: `Performs a subsequent ordering of the elements in a sequence in ascending order according to a key.` So you cant run it alone (or in a loop) like that.  If you truly think that "9" should sort *higher* than "10", then you can just compare strings.  Be warned that if.when you do have data like `{"10", "abc", "1abc5d"}` it may not work like you think.  Numbers do not sort the same way strings do and there is a special sprt to handle mised alpha-num.    I have edited your post to remove the new question since there are already answers posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end my solution had worked all along. The problem was this line:

```
Dim maxSorts As Integer = sorted.Max(Function(x) If(x.Sorts Is Nothing, 0, x.Sorts.Length))
For i = 0 To maxSorts
```

I should have caught this sooner, but it slipped by me. Getting the Max array length to iterate through is 1-based, but the array elements start at 0. I was actually sorting the list one too many times, which was resetting the sort order. Silly issue.

Answer (score 2):

I would just concatenate the strings in the `Sorts` array and sort by that combined string.

Comment: That would work unless that glob at the bottom of the post is the "string" array.  Joining numerals wont work {"20","35"} becomes "2035" and sorts lower than {"40"}.  I like the puzzle aspect, but there are many details missing.

Comment: As long as the sorting is done on the joined string, I think the numbers would be done correctly, but OP needs to be more specific before much more of an answer can be given. If the joined strings were then converted to integers, I don't think it would be right.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot we dont know.  This assumes:

- The block at the bottom represents the "string" array (even though ints are represented).
- You want a missing element(s) to sort higher than the rest
- Its not clear if there can be empty strings as well

---

```
Dim sorts As String() = {"10", "35", "20", "50", "40"}

Dim matList As New List(Of MatrixComponent)

matList.Add(New MatrixComponent With {.Id = 1, .Matrix = 1})
matList.Add(New MatrixComponent With {.Id = 99, .Matrix = 9})
matList.Add(New MatrixComponent With {.Id = 78, .Matrix = 7})
matList.Add(New MatrixComponent With {.Id = 4, .Matrix = 6})
matList.Add(New MatrixComponent With {.Id = 43, .Matrix = 3})
matList.Add(New MatrixComponent With {.Id = 123, .Matrix = 12})

' add randomized sort data
For Each m In matList
    ' sets a random number 0-3 values
    m.Sorts = sorts.OrderBy(Function(r) RNG.Next()).Take(RNG.Next(0, 3)).ToArray
Next
' force a "" into one of them:
matList(2).Sorts = {"", "10", "35", "60", "20"}

Dim sortedlist = matList.OrderBy(Function(x) GetSortValue(x.Sorts, 0)).
                    ThenBy(Function(y) GetSortValue(y.Sorts, 1)).
                    ThenBy(Function(z) GetSortValue(z.Sorts, 2)).ToList()
```

Then a helper:

```
Private Function GetSortValue(strArry As String(), ndx As Int32) As Int32
    Dim intVal As Int32 = Int32.MaxValue

    If ndx < strArry.Length Then
        If Int32.TryParse(strArry(ndx), intVal) Then
            Return intVal
        Else
            Return Int32.MaxValue
        End If
    End If
    Return intVal
End Function
```

The helper parses the string (if it exists) to an integer and returns a high default value if and when they do not.  Technically, its not entirely a one line linq chain.  The helper could be replaced with 1-2 `x = If()` operators, but I am not sure pasting that in there 3 times would make it clearer.

Test:

```
For Each m In sortedlist
    Console.WriteLine("{0:000}  {1}", m.Id, String.Join(", ", m.Sorts))
Next
```

Output:

> ```
> 078  20, 10, 35, 60, 
> 004  20, 10
> 099  35, 20
> 123  40
> 001  
> 043
> ```

(first digit is the Id)

---

I like the idea of a simple sort based using the concat of the string array.  This has limitations though: there can be no single digits (and maybe no `9`s).  For example, given the following data:

```
Dim sorts As String()() = {New String() {"10", "90", "20", "35", "40"},
                           New String() {"10", "9", "2", "35", "40"},
                           New String() {"1", "90", "9", "35", "40"},
                           New String() {"19", "90", "20", "35", "40"},
                           New String() {"20", "9", "20", "35", "40"},
                           New String() {"2", "90", "20", "35", "40"}
                           }
```

The results are quite wrong:

> ```
> 001  1090203540
> 099  10923540
> 078  19093540
> 004  1990203540
> 043  209203540
> 123  290203540
> ```

Number 78 was assigned `{"1", "90", "9", "35", "40"}` so it should sort to the top for the first element. The first nine in `"19093540"` which shifted over from the second group impacts the overall sort.  Sorted by numeric value:

> ```
> 078  1,90,9,35,40
> 123  2,90,20,35,40
> 099  10,9,2,35,40
> 001  10,90,20,35,40
> 004  19,90,20,35,40
> 043  20,9,20,35,40
> ```

the `123` element is even more interesting. The `"2"` should result in second place.  `"290"` is not the same and puts it at the bottom.

`String.Join`/ Concat can work but is *dependent on the nature of the data*.  If the string arrays are numerals and you want to sort by the numeric value, you have to convert them to numbers.  Numbers and Numerals sort differently.

Answer (score -1):

Does this work for you?

```
Dim sorted = _
    matrixComponents _
        .OrderBy(Function (m) String.Join("|", If(m.Sorts, { }))) _
        .ToList()
```

Comment: I do wish down-voters would provide a reason. I think this is a perfectly valid approach.